# Rename [pywikipedia] to [pywikibot]

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, retag-request, synonym-request

[Some questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/pywikipedia) but should be renamed as [the software was](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual:Pywikibot) some time ago.

The tag [pywikibot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/pywikibot) also exists now with 24 questions. A synonym is in order.